# SQL Server - recursive references (loop, join, insert?)

Tags: sql-server, loops, t-sql, left-join

I would appreciate if you could give me any hints regarding the fastest solution of the following SQL Server challenge:

Let's say I have a table with `DATE`, `CLIENT` and his several characteristics in other columns. I need to calculate `COLUMN_1` and `COLUMN_2` but:

- `COLUMN_1` uses the client's characteristics as of current `DATE` and as of previous `DATE` and `COLUMN_1` value from the previous `DATE` (recursive referencing)
- `COLUMN_2` additionally uses `COLUMN_1` value as of current date (therefore I would like to refer to its final value, not the particular 'case when' that implements the column logic)

How do I replicate this logic most efficiently in SQL Server?

I was thinking about the loop that goes over DATA and for each DATA, joins previous DATA, calculates firstly COLUMN_1, then COLUMN_2 (but how to make sure that the values in COLUMN_1 are accessible for COLUMN_2?)

Regards,
Bart

Comment: see the link referenced to know on  how to ask a perfect question:https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: I'm afraid this question is more about the conceptual solution than particular table and its fields

Comment: You probably need to make use of windowed functions, and either a recursive common table expression or a loop.

Comment: Can you make the question more clear? what is the input you have and what is the expected output required ?

Comment: Try using LAG & LEAD if using SQL Server 2012 or greater

Comment: It seems like some kind of weirdness... Think about stored procedure (standard tsql - process data to wanted apperance in several steps) and not about referencing of referenced reference :)

Comment: "Most efficient" requires appropriate metrics. Are you looking for the least heat produced by the server, smallest number of physical I/Os, most cache hits, ...?

Answer (score 2):

Without a specific example you we will not be able to tell you which solution would be the most efficient, especially when you are looking for a solution you describe as recursive. You might not need a full recursive solution if you could use window functions instead.

In sql server 2012+ you have access to [**`lead()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213125.aspx) and [**`lag()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231256.aspx) which you can use to get the previous and next values for a column based on a partition and order.

```
select 
    client
  , date 
  , nextdate = lead(date) over (partition by client order by date)
  , prevdate = lag(date)  over (partition by client order by date)
  , column1 = 'do stuff with lead/lag'
  , column2 = 'do stuff with lead/lag'
from t
```

rextester example: http://rextester.com/FFHU71709

returns:

```
+--------+------------+------------+------------+------------------------+------------------------+
| client |    date    |  nextdate  |  prevdate  |        column1         |        column2         |
+--------+------------+------------+------------+------------------------+------------------------+
|      1 | 2017-01-01 | 2017-01-02 | NULL       | do stuff with lead/lag | do stuff with lead/lag |
|      1 | 2017-01-02 | 2017-01-03 | 2017-01-01 | do stuff with lead/lag | do stuff with lead/lag |
|      1 | 2017-01-03 | NULL       | 2017-01-02 | do stuff with lead/lag | do stuff with lead/lag |
|      2 | 2017-01-02 | 2017-01-04 | NULL       | do stuff with lead/lag | do stuff with lead/lag |
|      2 | 2017-01-04 | 2017-01-06 | 2017-01-02 | do stuff with lead/lag | do stuff with lead/lag |
|      2 | 2017-01-06 | NULL       | 2017-01-04 | do stuff with lead/lag | do stuff with lead/lag |
+--------+------------+------------+------------+------------------------+------------------------+
```

---

One way to simulate lead/lag prior to sql server 2012 is with [**`outer apply()`**](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156(v=sql.105).aspx)

```
select 
    client
  , date
  , nextdate
  , prevdate
  , column1 = 'do stuff with lead/lag'
  , column2 = 'do stuff with lead/lag'
from t
  outer apply (
    select top 1 nextdate = i.date
    from t i
    where i.client = t.client
      and i.date > t.date
    order by i.date asc
  ) n
  outer apply (
    select top 1 prevdate = i.date
    from t i
    where i.client = t.client
      and i.date < t.date
    order by i.date desc
  ) p
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/GGS1299

returns:

```
+--------+------------+------------+------------+---------------------------------+---------------------------------+
| client |    date    |  nextdate  |  prevdate  |             column1             |             column2             |
+--------+------------+------------+------------+---------------------------------+---------------------------------+
|      1 | 2017-01-01 | 2017-01-02 | NULL       | do stuff with nextdate/prevdate | do stuff with nextdate/prevdate |
|      1 | 2017-01-02 | 2017-01-03 | 2017-01-01 | do stuff with nextdate/prevdate | do stuff with nextdate/prevdate |
|      1 | 2017-01-03 | NULL       | 2017-01-02 | do stuff with nextdate/prevdate | do stuff with nextdate/prevdate |
|      2 | 2017-01-02 | 2017-01-04 | NULL       | do stuff with nextdate/prevdate | do stuff with nextdate/prevdate |
|      2 | 2017-01-04 | 2017-01-06 | 2017-01-02 | do stuff with nextdate/prevdate | do stuff with nextdate/prevdate |
|      2 | 2017-01-06 | NULL       | 2017-01-04 | do stuff with nextdate/prevdate | do stuff with nextdate/prevdate |
+--------+------------+------------+------------+---------------------------------+---------------------------------+
```

---

For solutions that absolutely require recursion, then you probably need to use a recursive cte.

```
;with cte as (
  -- non recursive cte to add `nextdate` for recursive join
  select 
      t.client
    , t.date
    , nextdate = x.date
  from t
    outer apply (
      select top 1 i.date
      from t i
      where i.client = t.client
        and i.date > t.date
      order by i.date asc
    ) x
)
, r_cte as (
  --anchor rows / starting rows
  select 
      client
    , date
    , nextdate
    , prevDate = convert(date, null)
    , column1  = convert(varchar(64),null)
    , column2  = convert(varchar(64),null)
  from cte t
  where not exists (
    select 1
    from cte as i
    where i.client = t.client
      and i.date   < t.date
    )

  union all 
  --recursion starts here
  select 
      c.client
    , c.date
    , c.nextdate
    , prevDate = p.date
    , column1 = convert(varchar(64),'do recursive stuff with p.column1')
    , column2 = convert(varchar(64),'do recursive stuff with p.column2')
  from cte c
    inner join r_cte p
      on c.client = p.client
     and c.date   = p.nextdate
)
select *
from r_cte
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/LKH38243

returns:

```
+--------+------------+------------+------------+-----------------------------------+-----------------------------------+
| client |    date    |  nextdate  |  prevdate  |              column1              |              column2              |
+--------+------------+------------+------------+-----------------------------------+-----------------------------------+
|      1 | 2017-01-01 | 2017-01-02 | NULL       | NULL                              | NULL                              |
|      2 | 2017-01-02 | 2017-01-04 | NULL       | NULL                              | NULL                              |
|      2 | 2017-01-04 | 2017-01-06 | 2017-01-02 | do recursive stuff with p.column1 | do recursive stuff with p.column2 |
|      2 | 2017-01-06 | NULL       | 2017-01-04 | do recursive stuff with p.column1 | do recursive stuff with p.column2 |
|      1 | 2017-01-02 | 2017-01-03 | 2017-01-01 | do recursive stuff with p.column1 | do recursive stuff with p.column2 |
|      1 | 2017-01-03 | NULL       | 2017-01-02 | do recursive stuff with p.column1 | do recursive stuff with p.column2 |
+--------+------------+------------+------------+-----------------------------------+-----------------------------------+
```

Reference

- [Recursive Queries Using Common Table Expressions (cte)](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243(v=sql.105).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

If using SQL2012 or later, look at the features [LAG](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql) & [LEAD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lead-transact-sql)

For example, if you want to use the previous row's value in conjunction with this row's value - LAG like this:

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (DateCol DATETIME, StringCol VARCHAR(10))
INSERT INTO @T (DateCol, StringCol) VALUES ('2017-01-01','A'), ('2017-01-02','B'), ('2017-01-03','C'), ('2017-01-04','D'), ('2017-01-05','E')
SELECT DateCol, StringCol, PreviousRowStringcol = LAG(StringCol,1,NULL) OVER (ORDER BY DateCol) FROM @T
```